Is it possible to return the MAX of a SUM in a stored function? MYSQL
I am working with a database for an animal sanctuary where people can make donations to specific animals. I am trying to create a function that would return which animal a donor has donated to the most. The table I am working on is called donations and the columns are donation_id, donor_id, animal_id, amount, and date_donated.
I have tried this query(and alterations of it) but continuously have gotten errors. I am hoping to have the function return favAnimal as the animal_id of the animal the selected donor has donated to the most.
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION FindFavAnimal(p_donor_id INT(3))
RETURNS INT(3)
BEGIN
  DECLARE favAnimal INT(3)

  SELECT SUM(amount) AS sum_amount
  FROM donations
  WHERE donor_id = p_donor_id
  GROUP BY animal_id;

  SET favAnimal = MAX(sum_amount);
   
   RETURN favAnimal;
END //
DELIMITER ;

Any help is greatly appreciated!

always share exactly what errors the code you show give

first concentrate on getting a query that gives you the result you want, don't complicate things by putting it in a function before it works.

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question

Just add ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC LIMIT 1 and then select the animal_id

A tip about MySQL, not related to your question: Just use INT, not INT(3). The optional length syntax on integers doesn't mean what you think it means. It's finally deprecated in MySQL 8.0.

CREATE FUNCTION FindFavAnimal(p_donor_id INT)
RETURNS INT
RETURN ( SELECT animal_id
         FROM donations
         WHERE donor_id = p_donor_id
         GROUP BY 1
         ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC, animal_id LIMIT 1
       );

Neither BEGIN-END nor DELIMITER needed.
PS. Your function name seems to be not correct - you return maximal donation sum, not according animal ID/name.

if there's a tie, this will return one of the tied animals, but not necessarily consistently.  better to make it consistent with order by 1 desc, animal_id

fixed to do that and actually return the animal, not the amount.
